# Parsing html with changing div id

Tags: html, parsing, jsoup

I'm trying to parse the following `HTML` in order to get to the link that I marked below by using `jsoup`:

[image]

In order to do so, I did the following:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse( url );
Elements links = doc.select(".list-item-wrapper").select(".list-item")----> HERE IM STUCK
```

I would have continued by using:

```
doc.select(".list-item-wrapper").select(".list-item").select(#SEARCH_RESULT_RECORDID_dedupmrg914683993).select()....
```

But the problem is that `_dedupmrg914683993` is changed between every page.

I also tried:

```
doc.select(".list-item-wrapper").select(".list-item").select(.list-item-primary-content result-item-primary-content layout-row).select()....
```

But I got 0 results.

How can I parse it so I could get eventually to the link inside `<img class="main-img fan-img-1"...>`?

Thank you

Comment: If you provide the **URL**, we could check what is going on.  It's likely a `<SCRIPT ...> ... </SCRIPT>` loaded page, and therefore your `<IMG ID=...>` element would not be available to **Jsoup** without more steps.

Comment: ***MOST IMPORTANT:*** Anytime you see an **HTML** page with a lot of attributes that start with **ng-**, it means the page does contain **Angular Java Script** meaning that there is a lot of processing being done by the web-browser on the page that is initially loaded.  What you see (in the **image** that you uploaded) when you click your browser's **View Source** button is ***very different*** from what **Jsoup** initially retrieves from the web-server.  **Angular JS** is difficult.

Comment: @Y2020-09 you are more than right, I had to set a timer to let the page load completely and only then I use jsoup.

Comment: The `<IMG ...>` hilited in your picture (in your question) has the attributes: `ng-class=...` and also `ng-if=...` and `ng-src=...` among others.  The browser does a lot of processing that **Jsoup** will not do, no matter how long you wait...

Comment: Do you mean that by using jsoup I just cant to get the image in this case?

Comment: You might have to do more.  I do not have the **URL**, and cannot see the "initial page" - ***Specifically*** without the **URL**, I couldn't tell you what the **Jsoup** is even seeing.  What I can say (again), is that if you have used the proper selector - ***given the HTML you see using the `View Source` button*** - and you aren't retrieving the `<IMG ...>`, then likely there is script (**Angular** to be specific), and you will have to "do more" to get the `<IMG ...>`.

Comment: If you post the **URL** that contains the `<IMG>`, I'll look at it tomorrow morning....

Answer (score 1):

You can search for string match on any attribute, if your id always start with SEARCH_RESULT_RECORDID string you can look for it using the following syntax

```
doc.select(".list-item-wrapper").select(".list-item").select('[id^=SEARCH_RESULT_RECORDID]').select()....
```

I assuming that selectors are using jquery scheme

Comment: So I tried to use doc.select(".list-item-wrapper").select(".list-item").select("[id^=SEARCH_RESULT_RECORDID]").select(".result-item-image layout-column") but I wont let me proceed  with the tree. It indeed let me get some data tho but not what I try to do.